# .htaccess redirect without query parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, seo

I changed a website and now Google webmaster is loading hundreds of "Not Found" URLs:

```
http://www.domain.com/images/picture.php?idphotos=720,404,,4/1/13,Not found
```

The picture.php does not exist anymore so I created a .htaccess entry to redirect the root of the site:

```
Redirect 301 /images/picture.php. /
```

Now the problem is that any query parameters are also sent in the redirect:

```
http://www.domain.com/?idphotos=720
```

How can I create a redirection which doesn't include the query parameters, e.g. like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (note the trailing `?`):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.com/?
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively use the QSD flag from Apache 2.4.0

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""    
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301,QSD]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd